# Yup validation for array of objects required when a field match a condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, validation, formik, yup

i want to have yup validation for this shape of data :

```
{
   "values": [
      {
         "id": "Card ID",
         "checkBox": true,
         "csvField": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "title",
         "checkBox": false,
         "csvField": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "subtitle",
         "checkBox": false,
         "csvField": ""
      },
      {
         "id": "phase",
         "checkBox": false,
         "csvField": "",
         "fields": [
            {
               "id": "61d5bc37b995d200116bc73c",
               "phaseInCsv": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "61d5c43759bd07001134076a",
               "phaseInCsv": ""
            },
            {
               "id": "6203f08dc0eb7000120052a1",
               "phaseInCsv": ""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

so the validation of the fields array should happen only once the id = phase
i did it this way but didn't work !

any suggestions guys !

---

this is my validation but it doesn't work :

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    values: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        id: Yup.string(),
        checkBox: Yup.boolean(),
        csvField: Yup.string().when('checkBox', {
          is: true,
          then: Yup.string().required(
            t('IMPORT.VALIDATION_ERROR.CSV_FIELD_MISSING')
          ),
        }),
        fields: Yup.array().when('id', {
          is: FormFieldType.PHASE,
          then: Yup.array()
            .of(
              Yup.object().shape({
                id: Yup.string(),
                phaseInCsv: Yup.string().required(
                  t('IMPORT.VALIDATION_ERROR.CSV_FIELD_MISSING')
                ),
              })
            )
            .required(),
        }),
      })
    ),
  })
```